# Xcode storyboard outlet for navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am trying to implement what I found in [this](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html) tutorial myself, so I downloaded the project used in the tutorial from github ([here](https://github.com/objcio/issue5-view-controller-transitions))

The project has a storyboard with three ViewControllers: a navigation controller, the root view controller and a third ViewController. There is a push segue between the root ViewController and the third ViewController, the purpose of the tutorial is creating a custom transition animation.

The `NavigationController` is set as an outlet property in the `NavigationControllerDelegate` class:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Also, the delegate of the navigationController is also set to the `NavigationControllerDelegate` class.
My question is how was this achieved using IB and Xcode?
In my project I tried pulling an outlet from the storyboard to a property in my own `NavigationControllerDelegate` class without success. And I also can't find a way to set the delegate of the `NavigationController` to my `NavigationControllerDelegate class` using the Xcode interface.
Here's a print screen of how that looks in the project:

[image: print-screen]

Can someone please explain how this can be done using the Xcode gui?

Comment: crete a class subclass of uinavigationcontroller and set the storyboard navigationcontroller class to this then you can set this

Comment: @BHASKAR I know that there are other ways of doing this, like subclassing `UINavigationController' but I'm trying to find out how to get the @property IBOutlet navigationController like in the screenshot. It's not mandatory for the task but I'm trying to understand how I can use Xcode to do that.